# Where to find Firebase deploy error logs?

Tags: firebase, logging, npm, deployment, google-cloud-functions

I did `firebase deploy --only functions:helloWorld` using the Firebase CLI to deploy my function.

This is what I see on the terminal:

```
Build failed: npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /builder/home/.npm/_logs/2020-09-03T11_53_55_738Z-debug.log; Error ID: 49341d49
```

And on the GCP logs:

```
Cloud Functions
UpdateFunction
us-central1:helloWorld
me@gmail.com
Build failed: npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR! /builder/home/.npm/_logs/2020-09-03T10_51_08_513Z-debug.log; Error ID: 49341d49
```

The question is, **where can I find this file** `/builder/home/.npm/_logs/2020-09-03T10_51_08_513Z-debug.log` to inspect its contents?

I opened GCP's cloud shell but there's no such folder as `/builder` when I `ls` from root

EDIT:

While running `npm cache clear` I saw these logs and thought that there might be something under `/Users/me/home/.npm/_logs`:

```
npm ERR! As of npm@5, the npm cache self-heals from corruption issues and data extracted from the cache is guaranteed to be valid. If you want to make sure everything is consistent, use 'npm cache verify' instead. On the other hand, if you're debugging an issue with the installer, you can use `npm install --cache /tmp/empty-cache` to use a temporary cache instead of nuking the actual one.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you're sure you want to delete the entire cache, rerun this command with --force.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/me/.npm/_logs/2020-09-03T16_43_51_810Z-debug.log
```

so I went ahead and did `ls -als ~/.npm/_logs/` and I see some older logs on there but nothing matching `2020-09-03T10_51_08_513Z-debug.log` or newer ones that would have been generated by more recent `firebase deploy` commands

Comment: Hi, this link may slightly help you https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/issues/424

Comment: Hi @MartinKarari, I am not quite sure what to make of the thread you shared - what I should be looking out for in that link? Anything specific from it that you can point out in relation to my question?

Answer (score -1):

You view logs from the Cloud Functions in the Firebase console as the screenshot
[image]

Or Using the Firebase CLI
To view logs with the firebase tool, use the functions:log command:

`firebase functions:log`

To view logs for a specific function, provide the function name as an argument:

`firebase functions:log --only <FUNCTION_NAME>`

For the full range of log viewing options, view the help for functions:log:

`firebase help functions:log`

Comment: Appreciated. The Firebase Console logs look to me clones of the GCP logs since Firebase projects are backed by GCP anyway. What I'm really looking for is where the npm "builder" folder logs go to (as described in the question). Often I run into deployment errors and I would like to see details of the failures

Comment: since you are hit the 'Build failed: npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded', I guess you intend to access the log to understand the error ， is that correct? Since you could not find the route, It seems you need to [manually change npm's default directory](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally). The, remove the current build, Run 'npm uninstall' clean the cache Run 'npm cache clean --force' and then 'npm install' then you can rebuild again. Let me know if the issue persists.

Comment: yes I am trying to access the logs to understand the error. What is typically npm's default directory on macOS? I looked at the link you shared but it's talking about setting the global installation directory. I would prefer to use the normal node_modules directory on the current module. Btw I use nvm, I'm not sure if that makes a difference (https://flaviocopes.com/where-npm-install-packages/ suggests that it might)

Comment: You have to npm (the Node Package Manager) to install the CLI and enable the globally available firebase command. You can follow [Install the Firebase CLI on Mac OS documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli?#install-cli-mac-linux).